# How to grab the values from an HTML table's cells using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, cell

I'm trying to grab the cell values from an HTML table so that I can save them into a MySQL table via a call to PHP.  I'd like to use JavaScript rather than jQuery.

I'm giving each TR a distinct ID based on the MySQL table's ID field.  Also, each TD input cell has a unique ID based on the MySQL table's ID field.  Not sure if I need all those, but I used them.

How do I grab the cell's value so that I can pass it to a PHP procedure(I know how to code this PHP) to save the data into MySQL?  My JavaScript code below grabs the "innerHTML" but I need to grab the cell value's instead.

For example, if I have 3 rows of data from a MySQL table, with fields id and amount, with values below, how do I grab the "3" and the "1.99"?:

```
id    amount
-------------
1     100.00
2     9.99
3     1.99
```

**Here is a sample of the PHP/HTML code for the table, submit button and onclick call:**
(this is a very simplified version of my actual code but should convey the idea)

```
<?php
    /* define mysql database connect, query and execute it returning result set into $result, id=integer primary key, is_active=tinyint(0 or 1), amount=decimal(12,2) */
    /* ... */    
    /* output form/table */
    echo "<form id='myform' name='myform' >" ;    
        echo "<table id='mytable' name='mytable'>" ;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $id                 = $row['id'] ;
                $amount             = $row['amount'] ;                
                $tr_id              = "tr_id_" . trim((string)$id) ;                                                
                $td_id              = "td_id_" . trim((string)$id) ;  
                $td_amount_id       = "td_amount_id_" . trim((string)$id) ;                 
                $input_amount_id    = "input_amount_id_" . trim((string)$id) ;
                echo "<tr id='$tr_id' name='$tr_id'>";
                    echo "<td id='$td_id_account' > $id </td>" ; 
                    echo "<td id='$td_amount_id' > <input type='text' id='$input_amount_id' value=$amount > $amount </td>" ;             
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>" ; 
    /* submit button and onclick call */
    echo "<br />" ;
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>" ;
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<button type='button' " . 'onclick="SubmitTableData(\'' . "mytable" .'\');"' . ">Submit</button>" ;
            echo "</td>" ;
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";         
?>
```

**And here is a sample of my JavaScript function used to loop through the rows of the HTML table:**

```
function SubmitTableData(TableID)
{
    var table = document.getElementById(TableID);
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
    {
       // iterate through rows
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) 
       {
         // iterate through columns
            alert(col.innerHTML);
       }  
       /* call PHP procedure with row's cell values as parameters */
       /* ... */
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? There has to be a simpler way to do what you are trying to accomplish. Also, please post the **generated HTML** for the table, not the php that generates it.

Comment: My eyes.. that looks terribly complicated for no reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to grab cell values from a table?

#### Update to address Elliots comment

See [how to grab the cell value](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ8x6/5/) (innerText and data-value) in [my new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ8x6/5/show/)

In the table the attribute `data-value` is used to store some data (2B, 3C,..).

```
<table id="t2">    
  <thead>
   <tr id="tr1"><th>Student Name<th>Course</tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr2"><td data-value="2B">Bert2  <td>Economics  </tr>
    <tr id="tr3"><td data-value="3C">Clyde3 <td>Chemics    </tr>
    <tr id="tr4"><td data-value="4D">       <td>Digital Art</tr>
    <tr id="tr5"><td data-value="5E">Ernest <td>Ecmoplasma </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With jQuery and the right selector you can iterate over each cell:

```
function eachCell(){
    var cellInnerText = [];
    var cellValue = [];
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    var out2 = document.getElementById("out2");
    // iterate over each row in table with id t2 in the table-body (tbody)
    $('#t2 tbody tr').each(function(index){     
       // copy the text into an array
       cellInnerText.push($(":first-child", $(this)).text());
       //copy the data-value into an array
       cellValue.push($(":first-child", $(this)).attr('data-value'));
    });
    // show content of both arrays
    out.innerHTML = cellInnerText.join(" | ");
    out2.innerHTML = cellValue.join(" | "); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
If there were a value in each td, how would you grab that instead of the display text, for example, in the table below, how would you grab 1, 9, 33 instead of Red, Green, Blue?
<code>
<table id="t">
   <tr id="tr1"><th>id<th>color</tr>
   <tr id="tr2"><td value='1'>1<td>Red</tr>       
   <tr id="tr3"><td value='9'>2<td>Green</tr>       
   <tr id="tr4"><td value='33'>3<td>Blue</tr>             
</table>
</code>

Comment: @Elliot please take a look at my new demo and let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `innerText` property for the `td`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJE9c/2/) that shows how to use it.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1">Bla</td>
        <td id="2"><input id="txt" />Ble</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

JavaScript

```
var td = document.getElementById('1');
alert(td.innerText);
var td2 = document.getElementById('2');
alert(td2.innerText);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Place IDs on Your inputs with some pattern. for example `<input type="text" id="input_0_0" name="whatever" />` where `0` is row and second `0` is column and then instead your alert type

```
v = document.getElementById('input_'+row+'_'+col).value;
```

It should help You get rolling now

Answer (score 0):

Alert the innerHTML of the first cell in the table's first row

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to alert the innerHTML of the first cell (td element with index 0) in the table's first row.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```