# Get InnerText in html table cell and shape it to fit Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, google-visualization, innertext

I try to get the cellvalue of a table with a varying number of rows (generated from a 'while' loop in php) and shape them in order to fit in the Google Chart API.

Here is the table :

```
<thead>
    <tr>
            <th>Sport/Month</th>
        <th>January</th>
        <th>February</th>
        <th>March</th>
    </tr> 
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tennis</td>
        <td>Value Tennis.Jan</td>
        <td>Value Tennis.Feb</td>       
        <td>Value Tennis.Mar</td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Football</td>
        <td>Value Football.Jan</td>
        <td>Value Football.Feb</td>
        <td>Value Football.Mar</td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Sport_n</td>
        <td>Value Sport_n.Jan</td>
        <td>Value Sport_n.Feb</td>
        <td>Value sport_n.Mar</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to shape it that way:

```
[
      ['Sport/Month','Tennis','Football','Sport_n'],
      ['Jan',Value Tennis.Jan, Value Football.Jan, Value Sport_n.Jan],
      ['Feb',Value Tennis.Feb, Value Football.Feb, Value Sport_n.Feb],
      ['Mar',Value Tennis.Mar, Value Football.Mar, Value Sport_n.Mar]
    ]
```

In order to integrate it in that script :

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

I've tried to pick some code from here, using innerText, etc : [How to grab the values from an HTML table's cells using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074973/how-to-grab-the-values-from-an-html-tables-cells-using-javascript/13075924#13075924)

But my JS knowledge is limited so I couldn't get to what I'd like...

Comment: Couldn't you generate the js variable via PHP instead since you are already using PHP to generate the HTML?

Comment: Did you try anything? I mean can I see the code you have tried?

Comment: @Jay Yup, maybe I should try in PHP only... The problem is that I have complex query and php loop to generate the table and cells value so I wanted to avoid using them twice to keep the page code as clear as possible.

Comment: @MoazzamKhan I've tried to use the code from the link above but without success so far

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JS, this method may help -

```
/**
 * Pass this method table element, if you table id "t", use this method like -
 * getJSONArrayFromTable(document.getElementById("t"))
 * 
 * @param tableElement
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function getJSONArrayFromTable(tableElement) {
    var json = [];
    var rows = [];

    Array.prototype.push.apply(rows, tableElement.tHead.rows);  
    for ( var i = 0; i < tableElement.tBodies.length; i++) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(rows, tableElement.tBodies[i].rows);
    }

    for ( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        json[i] = [];
        for ( var j = 0; j < rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            json[i].push(rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    return json;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create arrays for each column then turn them into rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/N4Euz/

```
var $rows = $("table tr"),
    len = $rows.length,
    chartData = [],
    cols = [];


for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
  cols[i] = [];
  for(var y = 0; y < len; y++){
      cols[i].push(
          $rows.eq(y).find("td,th").eq(i).text()
      );
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    chartData.push(
        cols[i]
    );
}

console.log(chartData);
```